# Can IntelliJ's Remote Host sync .class files?

Tags: intellij-idea

Im using [Remote Host](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/remote-host-tool-window.html) in IntelliJ and it does not sync .class files; it does sync other files, such as .java files.

My setup:

1. IntelliJ 12 Ultimate on Windows 7
2. Ant build performing SSHExec on remote unix host to compile, jar, etc
3. Remote Host setup as SFTP (and FTP attmpted) on Linux host
4. Updating .java files (classes) do get synced/updated to the Remote Host

My goal: Start a remote debug session of a remotely running Tomcat 6, make minor updates to a class locally and have that class synced to the Remote Host with the aim that Tomcat would automatically load the new .class file.

I know the "hot swap" works since it works manually.
What's not working is Remote Host not uploading the newly generated .class file to the Remote Host.

Anyone able to do this?
Would there be a different plugin that should be used instead?

Comment: Class files are compiled into the output folder that is not monitored for changes by the IDE for the performance reasons (it's excluded by default). You can change the output to some other directory or do not exclude it from the project, this way IDE will be able to detect the changes and upload them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out that Remote Host only triggers when you save a file. 
Only then a file sync happens, but only on the file you saved/touched.
Remote Host does not 'listen' to see if just any file/folder was updated.
Hope this helps someone.

Comment: There is an option to [upload external changes](http://img542.imageshack.us/img542/9481/20130416230153.png).